# How to copy the current URL in Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I was sure in the version prior to 18.0 you could fiddle around and long press on the URL in the address bar and get a menu to copy the current URL.

I just updated Chrome, now if I long press it I just get the magnifying glass which is incredibly frustrating. How can I copy the current URL to the clipboard in the Chrome browser?

Chrome 18.0.1025469
Android 4.0.4
Sony Xperia P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out I was doing it wrong (well at least on my my ROM).

You need to perform two double-taps.

1. Double tap the URL. The first tap will select all of the URL and the second will deselect it and give you the text cursor and that little text selection tab helper thing.
2. Double tap the URL again to bring up the menu.

Or you can just keep quickly tapping until the copy menu appears. I find this whole process to be a bit unusual.

Other people are saying that they can long press to copy, so not sure if the above is specific to Sony ROMs.

Comment: Long tap works in my Galaxy Nexus, the steps you describe work here too.

Comment: Using Google Chrome 60 on Android 7.0 build by Sony, it only needs three taps. 1: open the search / address bar, select all of URL. 2&3 (double tap): deselect it then select all and show floating clipboard menu with text selection (teardrop shapes).

Answer (score 3):

It just might be about your ROM.

I have the same version of Chrome, on Android 4.1.2.
When I select the URL and long-press, I am getting a row of buttons, which of course includes a 'copy' button.

Comment: You could be right. This week I updated both the ROM and Chrome.

Comment: @row1 I'm also using the same Chrome version, but on Android 4.0.3, and can confirm that long pressing the URL does bring up the cut/copy/paste button bar.

Answer (score 1):

You could workaround this problem by sending the page to Gmail App, and there you can copy the URL from the draft message body. Then you can delete the draft from Gmail.

[image: Action bar --> Share...] [image: Select Gmail] [image: Copy URL from message body]

Comment: Have previously tried this. It is quite messy as you need to then exit edit mode (can't seem to select text), then load the draft (non-edit mode), then long press the URL to copy. Does work though. A share to clipboard app would be better.

Comment: Android 4.2 has the new sharing option "Copy to clipboard".

Comment: Thanks for the screens. I can't seem to copy it from your 3rd screen. I need to exit edit mode. Not sure if Sony will ever give me the 4.2 update ... well at least not any time soon :(

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "exit edit mode". Please could you explain better this? Maybe a screenshot could be helpful too.

Comment: Go back to your labels and selects drafts. Select a draft email. You are now previewing the draft and need to press the 'pencil' icon to edit it. I cannot select text from this preview mode, but if I long press on the URL I get an option to copy it.

Comment: When you share to Gmail app, don't you get directly to a Compose view? Is there, in the body of that message you will be now composing, where you have to copy the shared URL from. To go back like you say and do all these process you describe gets you exactly to the same Compose view I'm talking about.

Comment: Yes I go directly into compose view, but I cannot copy from compose view as it won't let me select or copy the URL. I need to go into preview view for the draft. The steps I described is not exactly the same. In preview view it will render the URL (blue text instead of plain), then I can long press on the URL I get an option to copy it. I cannot do this from compose view.

Comment: Definitely this must be a ROM issue, because it's affecting not only Chrome but Gmail too. Better go for my other answer: it's less complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this free app:  [To Clipboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.shiro.android.toclipboard)

Install it and it will be added as a new share option, so you can send there the URL from Chrome.

Comment: This works very well. Will wait and see if I can get any fixes/explanations for Chrome before accepting.

Comment: I don't think this is a Chrome issue, but a manufacturer ROM related "feature", because I had all versions of Android since 4.0 until 4.2.1 in my Galaxy Nexus and I never had any problem to copy URLs in Chrome.

Comment: It was working a few weeks ago when I last tried it. Since then have updated the ROM and Chrome. So could be the ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Use share from more(3 vertical dots) besides address bar. You will get copy to clipboard from various options of sharing. (Android 4.2.2 on Sony xperia z)

Comment: If you don't have this, you can get it by installing [copy to clipboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.johanhil.clipboard)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome browser. Samsung 10" tablet.

1. Get the URL you want to copy on the address bar.
2. Scroll it as far right as it will go.
3. Touch the URL lightly and it will be selected in blue.
4. Very lightly touch an area on the left of the URL and pull it to the right.
5. You can now use the selector handle to select the new area.
6. Repeat until you have the http(s) showing and touch copy.